# Chisel3: How can I remove Input and Output in Bundle definition

Tags: chisel

If I have

```
class ios extends Bundle{
  val wen = Input(Bool())
  val wdata = Input(UInt(8.W))
  val rdata = Output(UInt(8.W))
}
```

With Flipped I can get something like

```
class flipped_ios extends Bundle{
  val wen = Output(Bool())
  val wdata = Output(UInt(8.W))
  val rdata = Input(UInt(8.W))
}
```

Can I gain something like

```
class plain_ios extends Bundle{
  val wen = Bool()
  val wdata = UInt(8.W)
  val rdata = UInt(8.W)
}
```

without copying, pasting and deleting the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `Output` and `Input` to a bundle, just like `Flipped`. `Output` will make all wires in the bundle outputs. Since output is the default, afaik, applying `Output` to your bundle should bring everything back to default orientation.